# Aborted (core dumped) using opencv_createsamples

Tags: linux, opencv

I have a cloud server with Ubuntu 14.04 x64

I'm trying to create samples with

```
opencv_createsamples -img pos/comedon1.jpg -bg bg.txt -info info/info.lst -pngoutput info -maxxangle 0.5 -maxyangle 0.5 -maxzangle 0.5 -num 300
```

with currently this files:

```
-opencv/
-- ...
-data/
-info/
-pos/
--comedon1.jpg
-- ...
-neg/
-- ...
-bg.txt
```

I have 1100 background images in `neg/` which are listed on `bg.txt`

I'm getting this error

```
Create test samples from single image applying distortions...

*** Error in `opencv_createsamples': free(): corrupted unsorted chunks: 0x0000000001c608e0 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

How can I know if I'm getting out of memory? or what may be causing it? what can I do to solve the error?

Comment: Did you try using much smaller parameters? Does it work for 1 file with 5-10  samples? (No experience with this software, just trying to provide a 2nd set of eyes). Good luck!

Comment: still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

**If your positive image size is bigger than negative image you can get this error.**

Your positive image measure must be smaller than negative image.

*So this project pos/comedon1.jpg size should bigger i think.*